# exec("dir") produces Exception: Working Directory:null Environment:null

Tags: java, android

I Write simple application on AndroidStudio, run my it on a Galaxy Device.
when I am trying to execute the linux `id` command, like so -

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id");
```

It works fine. But most other Linux commands, including `dir`,
produces

```
Exception: Working Directory:null Environment:null.
```

I added those permissions to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Do I miss permissions, or do I have to initialize some environment variables?
this is the method from mainActivity.java:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    TextView dataTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataTextView);
    String st = "", st1 = "";
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        while ((st1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
            st = "\r\nline: " + st1 + "\r\n";
            dataTextView.setText(st);
            System.out.println(st);
        }
        proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: " + proc.exitValue());
        dataTextView.setText(st + "exit: " + proc.exitValue());
        proc.destroy();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (e != null) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
            dataTextView.setText("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the _actual_, ***complete*** exception stack trace

Comment: 11-14 22:37:16.246 585-585/com.example.udi.checksum1 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-14 22:37:16.406 585-585/com.example.udi.checksum1 I/System.out: Exception: Error running exec(). Command: [dir] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: No, please [edit] your original post and add the complete stack trace (formatted as code, indent 4 spaces)

Comment: And please log `Exception.toString()` rather than `Exception.getMessage()`.

Comment: And now please format that illegible mess so we can actually read it. Code formatting please. You are wasting time.

Comment: *D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN*
*I/System.out: Exception: java.io.IOException: Error running exec().* *Command: [dir] Working Directory: null Environment: null*
*W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources:* *com.example.udi.checksum1 for user  0*
*W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources:* *com.example.udi.checksum1 for user  0*
*D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false* Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has a very limited amount of Linux commands natively, use ls instead of dir.

Comment: This link may help: https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference

Comment: For a list of all the available commands on your target,  run "ls /system/bin".